# how to move sprites in andengine

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi i am doing one app using and engine here when i click button that time i need to move two sprites sprites are moving fine, but my requirement now both sprites are in opposite direction  when click button both sprites want move then center screen when both sprites having some 100 distance i want stop animation.i tried using below code but its caluculating starting sprites positions,while moving time its not caluculating sprits postions can u any one help me....

```
  final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mPaddleTextureRegionbtn.getWidth());
    final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT -  this.mPaddleTextureRegionbtn.getHeight()) / 2;
    paddle = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mPaddleTextureRegionbtn, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    final PhysicsHandler physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(paddle);
    paddle.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);
 scene.attachChild(paddle);

 final AnimatedSprite banana = new AnimatedSprite(0, centerY,  this.mBananaTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    banana.animate(100);
    scene.attachChild(banana);

  final float centerX1 = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mPaddleTextureRegion1.getWidth()) / 38;
        final float centerY1 = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mPaddleTextureRegion1.getHeight()) /7;


     ButtonSprite moveRightButton = new ButtonSprite(centerX1, centerY1, this.mPaddleTextureRegion1, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                         float pTouchAreaLocalY) {      
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Pong.this, "Haiii-------------", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                     MoveXModifier mod = new MoveXModifier(2, banana.getX(), paddle.getX()-100);
                    banana.registerEntityModifier(mod);


                     MoveXModifier mod1 = new MoveXModifier(2, paddle.getX(),banana.getX()+100);

                    paddle.registerEntityModifier(mod1);

                }
            });
         }
 });



     scene.attachChild(moveRightButton);
     scene.registerTouchArea(moveRightButton);
     scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, it might Help you.

MoveXModifier mod = new MoveXModifier(2, banana.getX(), paddle.getX()-100,new IEntityModifierListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {

            banana.stopAnimation();
        }
    });
                banana.registerEntityModifier(mod);
```

Same you can do for next.

Hope this the answer of your question, i could understand.